# How to make string human readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a js file with the following code:

```
(function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = function(module) {\n\tif (!module.webpackPolyfill) {\n\t\tmodule.deprecate = function() {};\n\t\tmodule.paths = [];\n\t\t// module.parent = undefined by default\n\t\tif (!module.children) module.children = [];\n\t\tObject.defineProperty(module, \"loaded\", {\n\t\t\tenumerable: true,\n\t\t\tget: function() {\n\t\t\t\treturn module.l;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t});\n\t\tObject.defineProperty(module, \"id\", {\n\t\t\tenumerable: true,\n\t\t\tget: function() {\n\t\t\t\treturn module.i;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t});\n\t\tmodule.webpackPolyfill = 1;\n\t}\n\treturn module;\n};\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/module.js?");

/***/ })
```

How to beautify The string in the eval function? I tried using js beautifer websites but it doesn't work on the string inside eval function. Basically, the `\n` in the code should be converted to new lines for easier understanding off the code.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Copy that line to another file. Replace `eval` with `console.log`. Then execute that other file by running `node another_file.js`. If you are on Linux or OSX or linux on Windows or run in gitbash or some other posix terminal in windows you can save the code to a file by typing `node another_file.js > beautiful_code.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the back-tick character instead of quotes

```
eval(
  `module.exports = function(module) {
    if (!module.webpackPolyfill) {
      module.deprecate = function() {};
      module.paths = [];
      // module.parent = undefined by default
      if (!module.children) module.children = [];
      Object.defineProperty(module, "loaded", {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          return module.l;
        }
      });
      Object.defineProperty(module, "id", {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          return module.i;
        }
      });
      module.webpackPolyfill = 1;
    }
    return module;
  };


  //# sourceURL=webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/module.js?`
);
```

That way you don't have to use `\n` or `\t`